# issues with fork() and taking a file as input standard

Tags: redirect, input, fork

i have a program called tinydb this program use 4 fork() to create 4 child process called insert,delete,update,select .the parent process send message from the getline(cin,buffer) to the corresponding child by check the first word.the children process will execute the message and create a log file and cout the directory/name of the log file.
all are working when i send command to tinydb however when i try to use a file as a input standard for tinydb ,something is going wrong. ./tinydb student_db.bin < query.txt  on the console all i see is the cout of the parent process ,the cout of the child process is not shown and the child doesnt create a log file however when i try to use debug on clion for tinydb with the rediction input of clion = query.txt all work fine.the cout of children are shown the logs are made.
i really want to know why its wrong, thank you.

p.s : i can't find the tag for redirection of the input standard to a file.

find a way for my children to be able to cout to the terminal and create a log.

Comment: Please, share the code you tried to execute.

Comment: It works now even if i dont know why